# Comparison with string doesn't work in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Any idea why the `IF-ELSE` below works

```
def checkPrValidity() {
    wordCountStr = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff --ignore-space-at-eol $target_branch..PRbranch src | wc -l' 
    wordCount = wordCountStr.toInteger() //force conversion to int data type 
    if (wordCount == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        println("This is a valid PR, continue the job execution")
        return true;
    }
}
```

while the one below doesn't

```
def checkPrValidity() {
    wordCountStr = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git diff --ignore-space-at-eol $target_branch..PRbranch src | wc -l'
    if (wordCountStr == '0') {
        return false;
    } else {
        println("This is a valid PR, continue the job execution")
        return true;
    }
}
```

Why do i need to specifically convert a `string` to `Integer`, while it fails to compare it as a `string` data type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to add `.trim()` to your `sh`. Because in output there can be [new line](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script), which prevents correct comparison.

Comment: ahh, i think this sounds to be correct. But i will test it out and will let you know.