# Why does Groovy's .equals() fail in a jenkins pipeline script when interpolating parameters into a double quoted string?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

(Note:  I have looked at similar questions (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677494/comparison-with-string-doesnt-work-in-jenkins-pipeline) where the problem is failure to trim output from shell commands) but I think this case is distinct.)

I have a pipeline script in Groovy that uses parameters (via `properties([parameters([...`).  When I interpolate the value of the parameter into a double quoted string, it fails a `.equals()` check against both captured (by which I mean "captured *and .trim()d!*") stdout (which is my use case) and even a simple string literal.

I can work around the problem using `.trim()`, (even though you can see, both through my echoing them and checking the `.length()`, that there is nothing to `.trim()`), but I suspect that only "works" because it does an implicit `.toString()`--which is also a successful workaround.

This looks like a bug to me, but it's literally my first week working with Groovy, so perhaps I'm missing something--can anyone explain what?

Even a simple literal `"foo"` fails (i.e. `"foo".equals("${params.foo_the_parameter}"`).  Is the interpolated parameter some other kind of object or something?

[**EDIT** After getting the answer from @Matias Bjarland, I modified the code below to use println instead of shelled echo because it makes the output more concise.  The solution he suggested is reflected in a commented block.]

My groovy code:

```
node() {
    properties([
        parameters([
            string(
                defaultValue: 'foo',
                description: 'This is foo',
                name: 'foo_the_parameter'
            )
        ])
    ])

    /* this is what I learned from the accepted answer
    bob="${params.foo_the_parameter}"
    println("class of interpolated param is ${bob.class}")
    simple_foo="foo"
    println("class of \"foo\" is ${simple_foo.class}")
    */
    echoed_foo = sh(script:"echo 'foo'", returnStdout: true).trim()
    println "echoed foo is [$echoed_foo], params foo is [${params.foo_the_parameter}]";
    echo_foo_length = echoed_foo.length()
    dqs_foo_length = "${params.foo_the_parameter}".length()
    println "their lengths are: echo: [$echo_foo_length] and dqs: [$dqs_foo_length]";
    if (echoed_foo.equals("${params.foo_the_parameter}")) {
        println "SUCCESS they are equals()"
    }
    else {
        println "FAIL they are not equals()" //this one fires
    }
    if (echoed_foo.equals("${params.foo_the_parameter}".trim())) {
        println "SUCCESS they are equals() after the dqs gets a trim()" //this one fires
    }
    else {
        println "FAIL they are not equals()after the dqs gets a trim()"
    }
    if (echoed_foo.equals("${params.foo_the_parameter}".toString())) {
        println "SUCCESS they are equals() after the dqs gets a toString()" //this one fires
    }
    else {
        println "FAIL they are not equals()after the dqs gets a toString()"
    }

    if ("foo".equals("${params.foo_the_parameter}")) {
        println "SUCCESS at least a simple literal \"foo\" works"
    }
    else {
        println "FAIL even a simple literal \"foo\" fails to be .equals() with the interpolated parameter" //this one fires
    }
}
```

Jenkins output:

```
Started by user Michael South
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
Obtained jenkins.groovy from git git@github.redacted.com:msouth/test_groovy_equals.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on subnet_mon_02 in /opt/jenkins/m1/workspace/field-analytics-org/test_string_equals
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] sh
[test_string_equals] Running shell script
+ echo foo
[Pipeline] echo
echoed foo is [foo], params foo is [foo]
[Pipeline] echo
their lengths are: echo: [3] and dqs: [3]
[Pipeline] echo
FAIL they are not equals()
[Pipeline] echo
SUCCESS they are equals() after the dqs gets a trim()
[Pipeline] echo
SUCCESS they are equals() after the dqs gets a toString()
[Pipeline] echo
FAIL even a simple literal "foo" fails to be .equals() with the interpolated parameter
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Office365connector] No webhooks to notify
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: In looking for "why does .equals() do this horrible thing" ;) I found this answer as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9682610/411177

Comment: Don't use Java's `equals`... Try `if (echoed_foo == "${params.foo_the_parameter}") {`

Comment: @tim_yates I just learned about that in further searching and was coming back here to put it as a second answer.  If you turn this into an answer, I will upvote it.  Here is a pretty good reference: https://objectpartners.com/2018/11/07/equals-is-compareto-and-the-groovy-identity-operator/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are hitting, but consider the following groovy code:

```
def x = 'World'
def gstr = "Hello ${x}!"
def str  = 'Hello World!'

println "class of gstr: ${gstr.class}"
println "class of str:  ${str.class}"

println(gstr.equals(str))
println(gstr.toString().equals(str))
```

which, when run prints:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy
class of gstr: class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class of str:  class java.lang.String
false
true

~>
```

in other words, a string interpolation will result in an instance of [groovy GString](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GString.html) which is not necessarily equal to the string with the same content. Forcing evaluation using `.toString()` solves this particular problem.

Quoting the [groovy documentation on string interpolation](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string):

> Any Groovy expression can be interpolated in all string literals, apart from single and triple single quoted strings. Interpolation is the act of replacing a placeholder in the string with its value upon evaluation of the string. The placeholder expressions are surrounded by ${} or prefixed with $ for dotted expressions. The expression value inside the placeholder is evaluated to its string representation when the GString is passed to a method taking a String as argument by calling toString() on that expression.

In other words, you have to either assign the GString instance to a plan java String using some variation of:

```
String str1 = gstr
def str2 = gstr as String
def str3 = (String) gstr
```

, call a method which takes a String (which will coerce the GString to a string) or call `gstr.toString()` to force the conversion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for--the answer to why the .toString() made a difference when it really, really, really seems like it shouldn't. Being a complete novice to groovy, you also taught me .class and that I can use println instead of a shelled out echo. Fantastic answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## In Groovy, you can simply use `==` to compare strings

In Java, you use `String.equals()` because `str1 == str2` doesn't do what you'd expect: Java compares the references instead of the values.

In Groovy, you can just write `str1 == str2` and it does what you'd expect it to do. Groovy compares the values using `String.compareTo()` and returns `true` when the result is `0`.

```
GString g = "${'foo'}"
String s = "foo"

assert g == "foo" && s == "foo"
assert g instanceof GString && s instanceof String
assert !s.equals(g) && !g.equals(s)
assert g.compareTo(s) == 0 && s.compareTo(g) == 0
assert g == s && s == g
```